# Backup DNS Server/s

Tags: scripting, batch-file, backup, dns

I have a problem with this script here

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netsh interface ip show config ^| find /i "DHCP Enabled"') do set DHCP=%%a
If /i "%dhcp%" == "Yes" (
    REM do command here
) Else (
    REM script to backup DNS servers to environment variables 
)
```

I've tried numerous ways using the first for /f example to try and get the DNS Server entries into environmental variables to be used later.

So basically I'm looking for a way to backup the dns server/s to environment variable/s (primary/secondary DNS) if DHCP is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

For this batch to properly run, make sure you **enable delayed expansion**. Just add `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of your batch file.

But it will not *"get the DNS Server entries into environment variables"*, which I believe is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx)  It is a lot more flexible than the old batch file way of doing things.

Comment: I would look into PowerShell, because I know its more 'powerful' :P
But the point of using Batch is to make it generic, and so it can run on all flavours of Windows (XP/Vista/7)

Comment: Powershell is available to be installed on everything from XP forward. 32 and 64 bit; desktop and server OS's.